# Having issues with byte array/capturing a screenshot

Tags: c, winapi

Hi guys I have the following code:

```
#define ScreenXResolution GetDeviceCaps(GetDC(0), HORZRES)
#define ScreenYResolution GetDeviceCaps(GetDC(0), VERTRES)

BYTE *screenData = malloc(sizeof(BYTE) * (3 * ScreenXResolution * ScreenYResolution));
captureScreenshot(&screenData);

void captureScreenshot(BYTE *screenData)
{
    HDC hdc = GetDC(NULL), hdcMem = CreateCompatibleDC(hdc);
    HBITMAP hBitmap = CreateCompatibleBitmap(hdc, ScreenXResolution, ScreenYResolution);
    BITMAPINFOHEADER bmi = {0};
    bmi.biSize = sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER);
    bmi.biPlanes = 1;
    bmi.biBitCount = 24;
    bmi.biWidth = ScreenXResolution;
    bmi.biHeight = -ScreenYResolution;
    bmi.biCompression = BI_RGB;
    SelectObject(hdcMem, hBitmap);
    BitBlt(hdcMem, 0, 0, ScreenXResolution, ScreenYResolution, hdc, 0, 0, SRCCOPY);
    GetDIBits(hdc, hBitmap, 0, ScreenYResolution, screenData, (BITMAPINFO*)&bmi, DIB_RGB_COLORS);
    DeleteObject(hBitmap);
    DeleteDC(hdcMem);
    ReleaseDC(NULL, hdc);
}
```

What I'm trying to achieve is taking a screenshot of their screen and putting it in screenData.

The reason why I  need that is so I can check if it's a certain RGB color at whichever position but I'm having issues doing so.

If anyone could help me out that would be greatly appreciated.

thanks!

edit: Added the memory allocation, The way I try to get the RGB is by a function returning a colorref like this:

```
COLORREF getRGBFromScreenshot(BYTE *screenshot, int x, int y)
{
    return RGB(screenshot[3 * ((y * ScreenXResolution) + x) + 2], screenshot[3 * ((y * ScreenXResolution) + x) + 1], screenshot[3 * ((y * ScreenXResolution) + x)]);
}
```

Comment: Is there a question here? What "issues" are you having?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have one, perhaps two problems.

The first is that you pass the argument as an address of the pointer, i.e. `BYTE **`. However, you only use it as a single pointer. This means that when you call `GetDIBits` it will fill in on the wrong address. You should have gotten a warning about this by the compiler.

The second problem is more potential, as there might be code you don't show, but it's that you never initialize the `screenData` pointer. You don't seem to be allocating the memory to copy the bitmap data into.

Both of the above problems will lead to *undefined behavior*, which might seem to work sometimes but not correctly, or may crash at any time.

---

As for the pointer issue, a pointer is exactly what it name says: It points to something.  In the case of your `screenData` pointer it can be visualized something like this:

```
+------------+      +---------------------------------+
| screenData | ---> | Memory allocated for screenData |
+------------+      +---------------------------------+
```

However, when you use the address-of operator `&` in the call to `captureScreenshot`, you are creating a new pointer to the `screenData` variable:

```
+-------------+      +------------+      +---------------------------------+
| &screenData | ---> | screenData | ---> | Memory allocated for screenData |
+-------------+      +------------+      +---------------------------------+
```

From the simple "pictures" above, it's easy to see why using `&screenData` will not work, it simply points to a completely different memory location.

Comment: Edited my post with the memory allocation sorry for that, I don't understand the pointer issue though :X Pointers are still confusing to me sorry.

Comment: Ok apparently I fixed it, I tried a bunch of stuff and understood what I was doing wrong thanks!

Comment: @user2204015 Updated my answer with an explanation of the pointer issue.

Comment: Thanks I appreciate that, while you're at it could you let me know if there's something I'm not doing right in my captureScreenshot function, if I loop that function my program seems to be taking more and more ressource even after the loop is stopped the memory doesn't go down, is there something I'm not releasing/freeing/deleting?

Answer (score 0):

As @Joachim Pileborg notes, `screenData` has to be pre-allocated an appropriately-sized buffer. If `screenData` is null, `GetDIBits()` only fills the BITMAPINFO structure (see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-nz/library/windows/desktop/dd144879%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)). If `screenData` is unassigned, it may point to a random part of memory and this will often cause crashes.

Either way, the code should check the return value from `GetDIBits()` to find out what is going on.

Comment: Edited the post with the memory allocation of screenData

Comment: Can you check the value returned by `GetDIBits()`? If the function fails it should be 0, otherwise it should be the number of scan lines copied from the bitmap.

Comment: just checked and it returns 0 :X

Comment: Thank you for your help I tried a lot of stuff and found out the answer! Thanks

Comment: @user2204015: To help other people in the future who have the same difficulty that you have had, could you post your solution as an answer to your own question? Thanks.